# Parsing JSON with varying value types with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON object and construct a String using the data. An example object I'm using looks like this:

```
{
    "age": 35,
    "name": "",
    "time": {
        "24hr": true,
        "12hr": false
    }
}
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
age - 35
name
time - 24hr:true, 12hr:false
```

I'm running into a problem since the keys have different value types. "age" has an integer, "name" has an empty string, and "time" has an object.

What's the easiest way to construct that output?

Currently, I have a for loop that can print out the keys, but the values don't appear correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have currently, not seeing why value types are mattering.

Comment: @tymeJV the issue is probably with true and false. I agree that seeing the current code will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues with most value types.

Here's a simple example that shows how you could do it without using recursion:

```
var o = {
    "age": 35,
    "name": "",
    "time": {
        "24hr": true,
        "12hr": false
    }
}, 
s = [],
x = [],
v, k, p;

for (k in o) {
   if (typeof (v = o[k]) === 'object') {
       s.push(k + ' - ');
       x.length = 0;
       for (p in v) {
           x.push(p + ':' + v[p]);
       }
       s.push(x.join(', ') + '\n');
   } else {
       s.push(k + ' - ' + v + '\n');
   }
}

console.log(s.join(''));
```

Obviously you could use a similar approach to dynamically construct some HTML structure instead of a string.

Comment: I wasn't using typeof to check for objects. Which is why I was running into problems. Adding this fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim, I'm glad I could help! Please note that you should probably generate some markup instead of a string if you plan to display the result in an HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/K55hv/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>age - </span>
    <span id='age'></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>name - </span>
    <span id='name'></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>time - 24hr: </span>
    <span id='24hr'></span>
    <span>, 12hr: </span>
    <span id='12hr'></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var json = '{"age": 35,"name": "","time": {"24hr": true,"12hr": false}}';
    var jObject = eval("("+json+")");
    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = jObject.age;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = jObject.name;
    document.getElementById("24hr").innerHTML = jObject.time["24hr"];
    document.getElementById("12hr").innerHTML = jObject.time["12hr"];
};
```

***NOTE: I highly recommend using a JSON parser instead of eval.***

*Example Libraries:*

1. [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)
2. [JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) *limited support*

### [Example using JSON2](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/K55hv/2/)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var json = '{"age": 35,"name": "","time": {"24hr": true,"12hr": false}}';
    var jObject = JSON.parse(json);
    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = jObject.age;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = jObject.name;
    document.getElementById("24hr").innerHTML = jObject.time["24hr"];
    document.getElementById("12hr").innerHTML = jObject.time["12hr"];
};
```